# Type of the positional parameters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm quite new to python programming and I come from a Unix/Linux administration and shell scripting background. I'm trying to write a program in python which accepts command line arguments and depending on there type (int, str) performs certain action. However in my case the input is always being treated as string.Please advice.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,sys,string
os.system('clear')

# function definition
def fun1(a):
           it = type(1)
           st = type('strg')
           if type(a) == it:
                c = a ** 3
                print ("Cube of the give int value %d is %d" % (a,c))
           elif type(a) == st:
                b = a+'.'
                c = b * 3
                print ("Since given input is string %s ,the concatenated output is %s" % (a,c))


a=sys.argv[1]
fun1(a)
```

Comment: Why not use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)?

Comment: You could try an isinstance(<value> , <type>) in an if - elif - else

Comment: i agree with TechieV2. isinstance() would probably be the easiest way to go.

Comment: A slight improvement is to use standard library: `from types import IntType, StringType` instead of `it` and `st`, but TechieV2s proposal `if isinstance(a, int): ...` is more succint.

Comment: @jamylak probably as the person is new, they never heard of argparse.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid maybe, I was unsure if they just wanted to reinvent the wheel as an exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the input will always be treated as string.

You could use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("cube", type=int,
                help="Cube of the give int value ")

args = parser.parse_args()
answer = args.cube**3

print answer

python prog.py 4
64
```

All the integers have an attribute __int__, so you could use that attribute to differentiate between int and string.

```
if hasattr(intvalue, __int__):
    print "Integer"
```

Comment: I think you mean `args.cube`

Comment: That's a bad way to check for an `int`. Use `isinstance(intvalue, int)`

Comment: Thanks again for your valuable feedback, I have rewritten using exception handling. I will now do it using argparse

Comment: @jamylak: That was straight from the python knowledge base http://www.thalesians.com/finance/index.php/Knowledge_Base/Python/General#Checking_if_a_variable_is_a_number_.28or_number_string.29

Comment: @BhavishAgarwal Yes that's checking for any **number** not strictly an **int**........... read the title of that section please (`Checking if a variable is a number`)

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments to Programs are always given as strings (this is not only true for python but at least all C-related languages). This means when you give a number like "1" as an argument, you need to explicitly convert it into an integer. In your case, you could try converting it and assume it is a string if this does not work:

```
try:
    v = int(a)
    #... do int related stuff
except ValueError:
    #... do string related stuff
```

This *is* bad design though, it would be better to let the user decide if he wants the argument to be interpreted as a string - after all, every int given by the user is also a valid string. You could for example use something like argparse and specify two different arguments given with "-i" for int and "-s" for string.

Comment: But wouldn't it be a problem if it is not a simple int/string case, to do a try except there ?

Comment: @TechieV2 And when exactly would a value contained in argv not be a string?

Comment: It shouldn't be. If the conversion to int failes, a ValueError will always be raised. If you wan't to treat different types in a different why then you'll have to do some further checking.

Comment: @l4mpi I think pypat has put what I mean in the question. Supposing my use case wants me to look at more than one kind of data, int/float.

Comment: @TechieV2 That would be a conceptual problem in itself as every int is also a valid float value. But the basic approach would still work - try to convert the value and branch depending on the success or failure of the conversion.

Comment: Thank you for you help, I will explore argparse and implement it

Comment: @syed.hamid no problem :) If you think this answer solved your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left, below the answer score (see also [this explanation about accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235))

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse, ast

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process a single item (int/str)")
parser.add_argument('item', type=ast.literal_eval,
                    help='item may be an int or a string')
item = parser.parse_args().item


if isinstance(item, int):
    c = item ** 3
    print("Cube of the give int value %d is %d" % (item,c))
elif isinstance(item, str):
    b = item + '.'
    c = b * 3
    print("Since given input is string %s ,the concatenated output is %s"
          % (item,c))
else:
    pass # print error
```